# grpc: received message larger than max (4623947 vs. 4194304)

Tags: go, grpc

Please help me
I've tried everything already
The grps settings are all indicated what else he requires from me

```golang
// client
sock, err := grpc.Dial(
    config.Parser,
    grpc.WithInsecure(),
    grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(
        grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(20*1024*1024), 
        grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(20*1024*1024)))
//...
m, err := d.Parser.UpdateSources(
    ctx,
    movie,
    grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(10*1024*1024), 
    grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(10*1024*1024))
```

grps still swears at a large message and, as you can see from the error, the settings were not applied
I also added options on the server

```golang
rpc := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(1024*1024*20), 
    grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(1024*1024*20))
```

result

> rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (4623947 vs. 4194304)

version grpc v1.41.0

Comment: Can you share some details about the API being consumed here? Provide an URL / instructions how to get access so it's possible to reproduce the error - or at least some background info on what you are doing and what your goal is.

Comment: looks (maybe) like a bug with the underlying library https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1382 try building with CGO_ENABLED=0 or CGO_ENABLED=1 to see if that affects anything.

Comment: you need to add details, like for example what is this grpc package? it's not obvious at all.

Comment: It's all about my curvature. I wrote the sending limit twice in the server setup.
grpc.MaxSendMsgSize (1024 * 1024 * 20),
     grpc.MaxSendMsgSize (1024 * 1024 * 20))
And I had a problem getting data over 4MB to the server.

Comment: Initially, I thought that because these are experimental settings, and they are already disabled. I started to downgrade. But this did not help and somehow accidentally saw an error although I reviewed it many times and how the blind person did not see a copy of the setting

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been resolved.
i missed setting `grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(1024*1024*20)`
I wrote twice `grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(1024*1024*20)` in server.
Lost all night due to a minor bug(